# How To Connect Specific URL of Api With Only 1 Mobile App

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I have an API and it has user register system.

The api is used by a mobile app. ( Most of URL's are not allowed for anonymous. Token key is used for all. **Excluding register URL**. )

And the register url has to be open. I mean that the url has no token key to be authorized. Because there is no authorized user. It is register level.

Of course, the register url open to attack. How can we prevent this situation ?

Comment: you could use an API key (rather an a user-specific token) and not reveal it except to the mobile app. And of course use HTTPS so that no-one can sniff the key by watching your traffic.

Comment: But the API key is open in APK ? API key is open to see in the code by using reverse engineering. I mean that,APK to code. Still not actual resolve.

Comment: what are trying to protect the register route from exactly?

Comment: API key is a pretty common method used by many apps on different platforms to limit the usage of an API. It's not foolproof but it prevents casual usage of a URL without working hard to obtain the key. One option in the APK specifically is that you can obfuscate your code and data strings to make it harder to work out the correct value. There are tools available for it. P.S. Exactly what risk are you afraid of? What kind of attack do you foresee and wish to prevent? The URL simply not being protected by an auth token is not, itself, a vulnerability if the URL doesn't logically require one.

Comment: My system is open the attack to create spam users. I must prevent this situation. @molamk

Comment: Why down vote me ? I found the answer which solved my problem, and my question is so clear to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options depending on your **threat model** and what you're trying to protect your endpoint from. Here are some of them:

- **[Rate limiting techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_limiting)** to prevent the endpoint from being blasted with an abnormal number of queries. For example you can **count the number of requests coming from a certain IP** address in a time window and if it's over a certain threshold, you block that IP
- **[reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html)** may also be useful. You can ask that **all requests to `/register` have a token that's obtained after solving the *captcha***. Very common technique against spam
- **[IP blacklisting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacklist_(computing))**. For example **IPs coming from the [TOR network](https://www.torproject.org)** can be blocked since all nodes are public. You can also include arbitrary IPs that may seem suspicious depending on your context
- **[User agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) blacklisting**. This may help if you want to limit [Web scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) activity. For example you can choose to only allow a certain set of *user agents* from mainstream web browsers

Comment: reCAPTCHA is very useful for me. Thank you so much !

Comment: @ŞerefCanMuştu My pleasure! [Here's a link to their docs](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3). Good luck